# Cannot remove element from boost::geometry::index::rtree by its index

Tags: c++, boost, r-tree, boost-geometry

I'm creating a [boost geometry rtree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_quickstart.html).

From the sample page I create:

```
typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
typedef std::pair<box, unsigned> value;
```

I want to add `value` elements to the tree:

```
bgi::rtree< value, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree;
box b(point(2.0f, 2.0f), point(2.5f, 2.5f));
// insert new value
rtree.insert(std::make_pair(b, 2));
```

Now I'd like to know if it's possible to remove an element by knowing the `box` identifier (or all elements of it if it's possible to set more elements with same id).

What I want to do is something like removing the element that I've added above like calling something like:

```
rtree.remove(2); // why I can't do this?
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use an iterator. The possible overloads are

> ```
> remove(value_type const &)
> remove(Iterator, Iterator)
> remove(ConvertibleOrRange const &)
> ```

First you should find the values to remove by searching (potentially running a query, but I assume you don't need that, because your problem would not exist.)

So, you might want to use `std::find_if`. I'm not sure how the performance can be improved (without resorting to a reverse map). I guess your profiler should be used for providing reassurance there.

### Update: Proof Of Concept

The naive approach fails:

```
// UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR:
template <typename Rtree, typename Id>
size_t remove_ids_loop(Rtree& rtree, Id const& id) {
    using V = typename Rtree::value_type;
    static_assert(sizeof(V) == 0, "don't use; UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!");

    size_t removed = 0;
    std::for_each(rtree.begin(), rtree.end(), [&](V const& v) { 
            if (id == v.second)
                removed += rtree.remove(v);
        });

    return removed;
}
```

This is because [as documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/begin__.html):

> #### ⚠ Warning
>
> The modification of the rtree may invalidate the iterators.

### Simple approach:

```
template <typename Rtree, typename Id>
size_t remove_ids_bulk(Rtree& rtree, Id const& id) {
    using V = typename Rtree::value_type;
    std::vector<V> v;
    std::copy_if(rtree.begin(), rtree.end(), back_inserter(v), [id](V const& v) { return v.second == id; });

    return rtree.remove(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

This sidesteps the race by doing the query separate from the removal. Note this might be more efficient because we pass the whole range at once.

> Note: this should be ok with duplicate entries, because `rtree::remove` only deletes one value at a time.

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9b84982a15d22c3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = bg::index;

typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
typedef bg::model::box<point> box;

typedef std::pair<box, unsigned> value;

template <typename Rtree, typename Id>
size_t remove_ids_bulk(Rtree& rtree, Id const& id) {
    using V = typename Rtree::value_type;
    std::vector<V> v;
    std::copy_if(rtree.begin(), rtree.end(), back_inserter(v), [id](V const& v) { return v.second == id; });

    return rtree.remove(v.begin(), v.end());
}

// UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR:
template <typename Rtree, typename Id>
size_t remove_ids_loop(Rtree& rtree, Id const& id) {
    using V = typename Rtree::value_type;
    static_assert(sizeof(V) == 0, "don't use; UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!");

    size_t removed = 0;
    std::for_each(rtree.begin(), rtree.end(), [&](V const& v) { 
            if (id == v.second)
                removed += rtree.remove(v);
        });

    return removed;
}

int main() {
    //I want to add value elements to the tree:

    bgi::rtree< value, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree;
    box b(point(2.0f, 2.0f), point(2.5f, 2.5f));
    // insert new value
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(b, 2));
    std::cout << "Elements: " << rtree.size() << "\n";

    // remove id 2
    remove_ids_bulk(rtree, 2u);
    std::cout << "Elements: " << rtree.size() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Elements: 1
Elements: 0
```

Comment: Add proofs of concept and fair warning about iterator invalidation rules.

Comment: A small remark, I know that you already addressed it in the update but to clarify. You wrote that "First you should find the iterator by searching for the value type". The `remove()` function taking a range/iterators expects a range of elements to remove, not a pair of iterators pointing to the elements stored in the rtree that should be removed. In other words, it doesn't work like `erase()` in STL containers, btw this is why it's called `remove()`.

Comment: @AdamWulkiewicz Agreed. Fixed the confusing wording.

Comment: Old question, but could you comment on the performance for remove?