# C++ Value at Recursive Struct Pointer Keeps Changing

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, heap-memory, boost-geometry

I am continuing my motion-planning algorithm with a recursive Node structure and a boost geometry rtree. However, I'm running into a couple of issues in which the value at a Node pointer keeps changing. Here is a MWE:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

using namespace std;

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;

struct Node
{
  struct Node *parent;
  point pos;
  int id;
};

typedef pair<Node, unsigned int> ptval;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian, pos.get<0>, pos.get<1>, pos.set<0>, pos.set<1>);

double px(point& p) {
  return pbruh.get<0>();
}

double nx(Node *n) {
  return px(n->pos);
}

double py(point& p)
{
  return pbruh.get<1>();
}

double ny(Node *n)
{
  return py(n->pos);
}

int main() {
  point start(0, 0), end(200, 200);
  Node *root = new Node;
  root->parent = NULL;
  root->pos = start;
  root->id = 0;
  Node *last = root;
  bgi::rtree<ptval, bgi::quadratic<16>> pts;
  pts.insert(make_pair(*root, 0));

  int c = 1; // running count
  srand(time(nullptr)); // seed rng
  vector<int> pars; // actual parent ids
  pars.push_back(-1);
  Node *save;
  int marker = 500;
  while (c<2000)
  {
    // generate random pos
    double xr = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 200;
    double yr = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 200;
    point random(xr, yr);

    vector<ptval> res;
    pts.query(bgi::nearest(random, 1), back_inserter(res)); // get nearest point in rtree
    Node *pnearest = &(res[0].first);

    Node *pnew = new Node;
    pnew->pos = random;
    pnew->parent = pnearest; pnew->id = c; if (c == marker) { save = pnew; }
    pars.push_back(pnearest->id);
    if (c > marker && c < marker+50 && save->parent->id != pars[marker]) { cout << "CHANGED " << c << " " << pars[marker] << " " << save->parent->id << " " << save->parent << " " << nx(save->parent) << " " << ny(save->parent) << endl; }

    pts.insert(make_pair(*pnew, c));
    last = pnew;

    c++;

  }
  cout << "ULTIMATE " << pars[marker] << " " << save->parent->id << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

An example output is

```
CHANGED 501 416 118 0x257c1b0 134.416 103.623
CHANGED 502 416 412 0x257c1b0 187.164 150.841
CHANGED 503 416 190 0x257c1b0 176.128 162.548
CHANGED 504 416 212 0x257c1b0 68.16 167.425
CHANGED 505 416 487 0x257c1b0 0.701926 114.237
CHANGED 506 416 61 0x257c1b0 16.8645 91.7386
CHANGED 507 416 221 0x257c1b0 160.991 62.9841
CHANGED 508 416 439 0x257c1b0 65.627 130.284
CHANGED 509 416 203 0x257c1b0 146.312 189.367
CHANGED 510 416 140 0x257c1b0 164.946 30.2683
CHANGED 511 416 76 0x257c1b0 193.194 146.336
CHANGED 512 416 286 0x257c1b0 29.8898 124.509
CHANGED 513 416 14 0x257c1b0 88.4732 88.3816
CHANGED 514 416 340 0x257c1b0 179.907 93.4538
CHANGED 515 416 409 0x257c1b0 26.5389 94.4609
CHANGED 516 416 488 0x257c1b0 98.8983 12.36
CHANGED 517 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 518 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 519 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 520 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 521 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 522 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 523 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 524 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 525 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 526 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 527 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 528 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 529 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 530 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 531 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 532 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 533 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 534 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 535 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 536 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 537 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 538 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 539 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 540 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 541 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 542 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 543 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 544 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 545 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 546 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 547 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 548 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
CHANGED 549 416 256 0x257c1b0 141.984 180.651
ULTIMATE 416 599
```

As you can see, for all of these iterations, `same->parent->id` differs from the actual id of the parent (416) when `same` was processed on its iteration, and for some reason `same->parent->id` fluctuates on these first few iterations. However, the pointer address remains the same. What is happening in the heap memory that is causing these values to fluctuate and then stop but still be at the wrong address? This is very weird. I suspect it may have something to do with the Boost RTree as I store a direct reference to each Node in it and Boost may be doing some underlying operations, but that is just a theory. I may also just be a bit misguided on how pointers work.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Comment: `Node *pnearest = &(res[0].first);` -- this looks like a really sketchy thing to do, when `res` is a local variable in your loop. You are pulling a pointer to a `Node` stored in that local vector, and you then store that onto a `parent` in your list. When `res` is destroyed for the next iteration of the loop, that pointer is dangling/invalid. Who knows what other dodgey stuff you're doing. I kinda stopped reading there.

Comment: *This is very weird* -- No, it isn't weird.  `Node *pnearest = &(res[0].first);` -- The program is broken, starting from that line and when the next iteration of the while loop executes.  Has nothing to do with Boost.  As mentioned already, `res` is recreated every time the loop executes -- that pointer from the previous iteration is now useless.

Comment: Have you been "a bit lazy in copypasting"? I cannot seem to find a definition for `px` or `py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm assuming the missing functions are:

   ```
   double px(point& p) { return p.get<0>(); }
   double py(point& p) { return p.get<1>(); }
   double nx(Node* n) { return px(n->pos); }
   double ny(Node* n) { return py(n->pos); }
   ```
2. The first real issue I see is:

   ```
   pts.insert(make_pair(*root, 0));
   ```

   That inserts a *copy* of the object pointed to by `root`. Any references will not point to the copy. `root` is always leaked for no reason.

   This is a better start that might actually work until the tree invalidates references:

   ```
   pts.insert(std::make_pair(Node{nullptr, start, 0}, 0));
   Node const* last = &pts.begin()->first;
   ```
3. Same here:

   ```
   pts.insert(std::make_pair(*pnew, id));
   last = pnew;
   ```

   `*pnew` is always leaked, and you didn't want `last` to point to it. To "fix" it naievely, I'd use a helper function:

   ```
   auto insert = [&pts](Node n) -> Node const* {
       pts.insert(std::make_pair(n, n.id));
       auto it = std::find_if(pts.begin(), pts.end(),
                              [](ptval const& p) { return p.second == n.id; });
       return &it->first;
   };

   Node const* last = insert(Node{nullptr, start, 0});
   ```
4. As others have noted, this is definitely wrong:

   ```
   ptval res;
   pts.query(bgi::nearest(newpos, 1), &res);
   Node* pnearest = &(res[0].first);
   ```

   This by definition takes the address of the local copy of a `ptval`'s Node element. Instead, let's use the same naive (probably enormously inefficient) approach:

   ```
   auto find = [&pts](int id) -> Node const* {
       auto it = std::find_if(pts.begin(), pts.end(),
                              [id](ptval const& p) { return p.second == id; });
       return &it->first;
   };
   auto insert = [&, find](Node n) -> Node const* {
       pts.insert(std::make_pair(n, n.id));
       return find(n.id);
   };
   ```

   Now you can have:

   ```
   Node const* last = insert(Node{nullptr, start, 0}); // insert root
   ```

   As well as:

   ```
       ptval res;
       pts.query(bgi::nearest(newpos, 1), &res);
       Node new_node{find(res.second), newpos, id};

       if (id == marker) {
           marker_parent = new_node.parent;
       }

       parents.push_back(new_node.parent->id);
   ```
5. Next up

   ```
   srand(time(nullptr));  // seed rng
   // generate random pos
   double xr = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 200;
   double yr = ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 200;
   ```

   Prefer standard library:

   ```
   std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};
   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 200);
   // generate random pos
   double xr = dist(prng);
   double yr = dist(prng);
   ```
6. Next up

   ```
   Node* save;
   ```
7. Prefer to initialize:

   ```
   Node* save = nullptr;
   ```
8. Know your loops.

   ```
   int c = 1;            // running count
   // ...
   while (c < 2000) {
       //...
       c++;
   }
   ```

   Should just be

   ```
   for (int id = 1; id<2000; ++id) {
       //...
   }
   ```

   Note the naming as well.
9. Don't use `using namespace std;` ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))

Applying all this leads me to:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/a4jv6jfT6)**

```
//#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string>
//#include <vector>
//#include <set>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <random>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;

struct Node {
    Node const* parent = nullptr;
    point       pos    = {};
    int         id     = -1;
};

typedef std::pair<Node, int> ptval;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian,
                                         pos.get<0>, pos.get<1>, pos.set<0>,
                                         pos.set<1>)

double px(point const& p) { return p.get<0>(); }
double py(point const& p) { return p.get<1>(); }
double nx(Node const* n) { return px(n->pos); }
double ny(Node const* n) { return py(n->pos); }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    point start(0, 0) /*, end(200, 200)*/;

    bgi::rtree<ptval, bgi::quadratic<16>> pts;

    auto find = [&pts](int id) -> Node const* {
        auto it = std::find_if(pts.begin(), pts.end(),
                               [id](ptval const& p) { return p.second == id; });
        return &it->first;
    };
    auto insert = [&, find](Node n) -> Node const* {
        pts.insert(std::make_pair(n, n.id));
        return find(n.id);
    };

    Node const* last = insert(Node{nullptr, start, 0}); // insert root

    std::mt19937 prng{argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 200);

    std::vector<int> parents{-1}; // actual parent ids

    Node const* marker_parent = nullptr;

    int marker = 500;
    for (int id = 1; id < 2000; ++id) {
        // generate random pos
        point newpos(dist(prng), dist(prng));

        ptval res;
        pts.query(bgi::nearest(newpos, 1), &res);
        Node new_node{find(res.second), newpos, id};

        if (id == marker) {
            marker_parent = new_node.parent;
        }

        parents.push_back(new_node.parent->id);
        if (id > marker && id < marker + 50 &&
            marker_parent->id != parents[marker]) {
            std::cout << "CHANGED " << id << " " << parents[marker] << " "
                      << marker_parent->id << " " << marker_parent
                      << " " << nx(marker_parent) << " "
                      << ny(marker_parent) << std::endl;
        }

        last = insert(new_node);
    }
    std::cout << "ULTIMATE " << parents[marker] << " ";

    if (marker_parent)
        std::cout << marker_parent->id << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Prints (with the seed fixed at 42 for online demo):

```
ULTIMATE 307 1622
```

The funny thing is, as far as I can see `last` is never used. So you can probably do with much simpler and more efficient:

```
auto insert = [&](Node n) { pts.insert(std::make_pair(n, n.id)); };
```

### Isolating The Bug - Root Cause

Note above when I said "*might actually work until the tree invalidates references*". Sadly I was unable to find **any** documentation of reference stability/invalidation guarantees for `rtree`¹.

With different seeds we still get output like e.g. for seed 47:

```
CHANGED 501 189 38 0x617000004e30 26.0044 140.042
...
CHANGED 549 189 38 0x617000004e30 26.0044 140.042
ULTIMATE 189 474
```

Obviously, at least all the lines are identical (except for the running counter 501..549). Comparing seed 40:

```
CHANGED 517 108 500 0x560957ad1638 109.71 53.341
...
CHANGED 549 108 500 0x560957ad1638 109.71 53.341
ULTIMATE 108 590
```

Illustrates that sometimes the marker "randomly" changes *during* the game. The problem then, clearly, is that `rtree` can reallocate, invalidating `Node` references.

The number 517 is interesting to me for its relation to `16` in `bgi::quadratic<16>`. So, I thought to make a much more granular test instead of randomly monitoring the 500th "marker". Why not monitor **all** parents?

```
constexpr auto N = 2000;
std::vector<Node const*> parents(N, nullptr); // parents refs
std::vector<int>         parent_ids(N, -1);   // parent ids

for (int id = 1; id < N; ++id) {
    // generate random pos
    point newpos(dist(prng), dist(prng));

    ptval res;
    pts.query(bgi::nearest(newpos, 1), &res);
    Node new_node{find(res.second), newpos, id};

    parents[id]    = new_node.parent;
    parent_ids[id] = new_node.parent->id;

    bool invalidated = !std::equal(
        parents.begin(), parents.end(), parent_ids.begin(),
        [](Node const* p, int id) { return !p || p->id == id; });

    std::cout << "invalidated: " << std::boolalpha << invalidated << "\n";
    //assert(!invalidated);

    insert(new_node);
}
```

Now running this a few hundred times with random seeds shows a pattern of always invalidating after 16 nodes:

```
$ for a in {1..100}; do ./build/sotest; done | uniq -c | sort | uniq
     16 invalidated: false
   1983 invalidated: true
      1 ULTIMATE 101 1393
      1 ULTIMATE 103 262
      1 ULTIMATE 103 5
      1 ULTIMATE 104 536
      1 ULTIMATE 108 1406
      1 ULTIMATE 111 111
```

This confirms beyond any statistical doubt that reallocation is causing the references (i.e. the pointers) to become invalidated.

### FIXING

I suggest keeping the parent references by `id` only. Interestingly, since `id` is already part of `Node` you can do without the duplication in `std::pair` by using a custom ``indexable<>`or custom`IndexableGetter` template argument.

Let's store *references* to `Node`s in the tree, instead, using a custom indexable:

```
using NodeRef = std::reference_wrapper<Node const>;
struct MyIndexable {
    using value_type  = NodeRef;
    using result_type = Node const&;

    result_type operator()(NodeRef r) const { return r; }
};
```

Now we can trivially build a tree from those:

```
bgi::rtree<NodeRef, bgi::quadratic<16>, MyIndexable> pts;
```

All we need is some *stable* storage for the referenced nodes:

```
std::deque<Node> storage; // reference stability adding/removing at either end
//std::list<Node> storage; // iterator and reference stability (except removed)

auto insert = [&](Node n) {
    storage.push_back(std::move(n));
    pts.insert(NodeRef(storage.back()));
};
```

The rest of the program can remain pretty much the same - except for a few respellings to accomodate `NodeRef`:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d796ec4129e3006a)**

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
#include <random>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;

struct Node {
    Node const* parent = nullptr;
    point       pos    = {};
    int         id     = -1;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(Node, double, bg::cs::cartesian,
                                         pos.get<0>, pos.get<1>, pos.set<0>,
                                         pos.set<1>)

double px(point const& p) { return p.get<0>(); }
double py(point const& p) { return p.get<1>(); }
double nx(Node const* n) { return px(n->pos); }
double ny(Node const* n) { return py(n->pos); }

using NodeRef = std::reference_wrapper<Node const>;
struct MyIndexable {
    using value_type  = NodeRef;
    using result_type = Node const&;

    result_type operator()(NodeRef r) const { return r; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bgi::rtree<NodeRef, bgi::quadratic<16>, MyIndexable> pts;

    std::deque<Node> storage; // reference stability adding/removing at either end
    //std::list<Node> storage; // iterator and reference stability (except removed)

    auto insert = [&](Node n) {
        storage.push_back(std::move(n));
        pts.insert(NodeRef(storage.back()));
    };

    insert({nullptr, point(0, 0), 0}); // insert root

    std::mt19937 prng{argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 200);

    constexpr auto N = 2000;
    std::vector<NodeRef> parents; // parents refs
    std::vector<int>     parent_ids; // parent ids

    for (int id = 1; id < N; ++id) {
        // generate random pos
        point newpos(dist(prng), dist(prng));

        std::vector<NodeRef> res;
        pts.query(bgi::nearest(newpos, 1), back_inserter(res));
        Node new_node{&res.front().get(), newpos, id};

        parents.push_back(*new_node.parent);
        parent_ids.push_back(new_node.parent->id);

        bool invalidated =
            !std::equal(parents.begin(), parents.end(), parent_ids.begin(),
                        [](Node const& p, int id) { return p.id == id; });

        assert(!invalidated);

        insert(std::move(new_node));
    }
    std::cout << "ULTIMATE " << parent_ids.at(500) << " "
              << parents.at(500).get().id << "\n";
}
```

Which never trips the assert, and produces stable output like:

```
for a in {1..50}; do ./a.out; done
ULTIMATE 41 41
ULTIMATE 365 365
ULTIMATE 219 219
ULTIMATE 193 193
ULTIMATE 448 448
ULTIMATE 331 331
ULTIMATE 227 227
ULTIMATE 234 234
ULTIMATE 300 300
ULTIMATE 227 227
ULTIMATE 243 243
ULTIMATE 248 248
ULTIMATE 233 233
ULTIMATE 143 143
ULTIMATE 39 39
ULTIMATE 488 488
ULTIMATE 493 493
ULTIMATE 9 9
ULTIMATE 212 212
ULTIMATE 338 338
ULTIMATE 141 141
ULTIMATE 356 356
ULTIMATE 147 147
ULTIMATE 376 376
ULTIMATE 76 76
ULTIMATE 450 450
ULTIMATE 272 272
ULTIMATE 34 34
ULTIMATE 492 492
ULTIMATE 478 478
ULTIMATE 84 84
ULTIMATE 416 416
ULTIMATE 222 222
ULTIMATE 457 457
ULTIMATE 95 95
ULTIMATE 446 446
ULTIMATE 233 233
ULTIMATE 480 480
ULTIMATE 265 265
ULTIMATE 415 415
ULTIMATE 289 289
ULTIMATE 121 121
ULTIMATE 344 344
ULTIMATE 110 110
ULTIMATE 429 429
ULTIMATE 31 31
ULTIMATE 344 344
ULTIMATE 172 172
ULTIMATE 20 20
ULTIMATE 394 394
```

### Bonus

A version without the now-redundant sanity checks and unused code: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52ef9d39cc930df6)**

---

¹ although there [are some notes about iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951426/cannot-remove-element-from-boostgeometryindexrtree-by-its-index#:%7E:text=The%20modification%20of%20the%20rtree%20may%20invalidate%20the%20iterators)

Comment: Added a working redesign that's both correct (no undefined behavior) and a lot more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Actually, I will need to use `last` eventually. I can see that many issue fixes relate to storing Nodes globally in this rtree and then setting pointers from there. It seems like using a vector to store Node references would be a lot simpler, and I actually used to do that but wanted to try this other approach to see effect on time performance. To derive the `pnew` pointer to set to `last`, I think that after inserting the Node into the Rtree, I can use a nearest query to extract pointer since coords are already known, as opposed to manually looping through.

Comment: Actually never mind, I am just realizing the stability of `storage` and can derive the pointer from there instead.